# Programmatically remove Apple Screen Capture Shadow borders

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

The built-in MacOS screen capture program (command-shift-4) has a nice feature where you can hit the spacebar and capture just a window, like this:

[image]

I would like to programmatically look at a directory of images (they are PNGs), determinate if they have the shadow, and automatically crop it. I need this to run on a Mac. I'd like to write this in Python. I am told that [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) is the correct way to manage images in Python now, but I'm not sure how to read individual pixel and to crop images.

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can take command+shift+4 screenshots with option+space and you don't get this border at all.

Comment: Thanks. Nice idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that uses Python Image Library and Python 2.7 to do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env                                                                                                                       
# Removes the shadow from MacOS-Generated screen shots.                                                                              

import Image,os

if __name__=="__main__":
    image = Image.open(os.sys.argv[1])
    image = image.convert('RGBA')

    (width,height) = image.size
    def find_first_non_alpha_x():
        for i in range(width):
            if image.getpixel((i,height/2))[3]==255:
                return i
        raise RuntimeError("No non-alpha pixels on midline")

    def find_last_non_alpha_x():
        for i in range(width-1,0,-1):
            if image.getpixel((i,height/2))[3]==255:
                return i
        raise RuntimeError("No non-alpha pixels on midline")

    def find_first_non_alpha_y():
        for i in range(height):
            if image.getpixel((width/2,i))[3]==255:
                return i
        raise RuntimeError("No non-alpha pixels on midline")

    def find_last_non_alpha_y():
        for i in range(height-1,0,-1):
            if image.getpixel((width/2,i))[3]==255:
                return i
        raise RuntimeError("No non-alpha pixels on midline")

    x1 = find_first_non_alpha_x()
    y1 = find_first_non_alpha_y()
    x2  = find_last_non_alpha_x()
    y2  = find_last_non_alpha_y()

    y = image.crop((x1-1,y1-1,x2+1,y2+1))
    y.save(os.sys.argv[1]+"-cropped.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some recommendations regardless of the library you will be using.

There are invariants on the window: 4 corners, title bar with mostly uniform color and 3 disk-shaped buttons.

If you can detect the buttons and the title bar, you can easily find the top corners. The bottom corners are symmetrical to the top corners.

A possible solution

- Apply [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to find circles
- Find 3 consecutive circles along the horizontal axis (the buttons)
- Apply Hough transform to find vertical and horizontal lines
- Find a quad containing the 3 circles (title bar)
- The 2 top corners of the window are located around the top corners of the title bar.
- Form a patch by taking a neighborhood around a corner
- Apply an [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) algorithm in the patch
- Reflect the pixels of the patch vertically
- Apply patch matching vertically. For example with [DP](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.189&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- Repeat the matching for the 2 top corners to find the bottom ones

With the 4 corner you know the bounding box of the window and you can solve the cropping problem

Comment: Actually, it's a lot easier. The shadow is always in the same place and the same color. I just want to verify that it's there and remove it. I'm looking for the specific Python calls to make using an image manipulation library. Perhaps this can be dome simply with ImageMagick?